# Neo4j indexes and legacy data

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gremlin

I have a legacy dataset ([ENRON data](http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/enron-email-data-with-manager-subordinate-relationship-metadata) represented as GraphML) that I would like to query. In an [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148032/using-a-legacy-neo4j-database-with-grails#comment-17916717) in a related question, [@StefanArmbruster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158701/stefan-armbruster) suggests that I use Cypher to query the database. My query use case is simple: given a message id (a property of the Message node), retrieve the node that has that id, and also retrieve the sender and recipient nodes of that message.

It seems that to do this in Cypher, I first have to create an index of the nodes. Is there a way to do this automatically when the data is loaded from the graphML file? (I had used Gremlin to load the data and create the database.)

I also have an external Lucene index of the data (I need it for other purposes). Does it make sense to have two indexes? I could, for example, index the Neo4J node ids into my external index, and then query the graph based on those ids. My concern is about the persistence of these ids. (By analogy, Lucene document ids should not be treated as persistent.)

So, should I:

1. Index the Neo4j graph internally to query on message ids using Cypher? (If so, what is the best way to do that: regenerate the database with some suitable incantation to get the index built? Build the index on the already-existing db?)
2. Store Neo4j node ids in my external Lucene index and retrieve nodes via these stored ids?

**UPDATE**

I have been trying to get auto-indexing to work with Gremlin and an embedded server, but with no luck. In the [documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/gremlin-plugin.html#rest-api-load-a-sample-graph) it says

> The underlying database is auto-indexed, see Section 14.12, “Automatic Indexing” so the script can return the imported node by index lookup.

But when I examine the graph after loading a new database, no indexes seem to exist.

The [Neo4j documentation on auto indexing](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/auto-indexing.html) says that a bunch of configuration is required. In addition to setting `node_auto_indexing = true`, you have to configure it

> To actually auto index something, you have to set which properties
>   should get indexed. You do this by listing the property keys to index
>   on. In the configuration file, use the node_keys_indexable and
>   relationship_keys_indexable configuration keys. When using embedded
>   mode, use the GraphDatabaseSettings.node_keys_indexable and
>   GraphDatabaseSettings.relationship_keys_indexable configuration keys.
>   In all cases, the value should be a comma separated list of property
>   keys to index on.

So is Gremlin supposed to set the `GraphDatabaseSettings` parameters? I tried passing in a map into the Neo4jGraph constructor like this:

```
    Map<String,String> config = [
        'node_auto_indexing':'true',
        'node_keys_indexable': 'emailID'
        ]
    Neo4jGraph g = new Neo4jGraph(graphDB, config);
    g.loadGraphML("../databases/data.graphml");
```

but that had no apparent effect on index creation.

**UPDATE 2**

Rather than configuring the database through Gremlin, I used the examples given in the [Neo4j documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/auto-indexing.html) so that my database creation was like this (in Groovy):

```
protected Neo4jGraph getGraph(String graphDBname, String databaseName) {
    boolean populateDB = !new File(graphDBName).exists();
    if(populateDB)
        println "creating database";
    else
        println "opening database";

    GraphDatabaseService graphDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().
        newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder( graphDBName ).
        setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.node_keys_indexable, "emailID" ).
        setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.node_auto_indexing, "true" ).
        setConfig( GraphDatabaseSettings.dump_configuration, "true").
        newGraphDatabase();
    Neo4jGraph g = new Neo4jGraph(graphDB);

    if (populateDB) {
        println "Populating graph"
        g.loadGraphML(databaseName);
    }

    return g;
}
```

and my retrieval was done like this:

```
ReadableIndex<Node> autoNodeIndex = graph.rawGraph.index()
    .getNodeAutoIndexer()
    .getAutoIndex();
def node = autoNodeIndex.get( "emailID", "<2614099.1075839927264.JavaMail.evans@thyme>" ).getSingle();
```

And this seemed to work. Note, however, that the `getIndices()` call on the `Neo4jGraph` object still returned an empty list. So the upshot is that I can exercise the Neo4j API correctly, but the Gremlin wrapper seems to be unable to reflect the indexing state. The expression `g.idx('node_auto_index')` (documented in [Gremlin Methods](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Gremlin-Methods)) returns null.

Answer (score 2):

the auto indexes are created lazily. That is - when you have enabled the auto-indexing, the actual index is first created when you index your first property. Make sure you are inserting data before checking the existence of the index, otherwise it might not show up.

For some auto-indexing code (using programmatic configuration), see e.g. https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/rabbithole/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/community/console/IndexTest.java (this is working with Neo4j 1.8

/peter

Comment: I modified the question once more to show that after I create the `Neo4jGraph` instance, I load the data from a graphml file. The load succeeds, as I can then traverse the graph, but enumerating indexes via `getIndices()` results in an empty list.

Comment: So, I don't think the autoindex is listed, as it is a built-in one.Can you search for stuff using it?

Comment: Yes, as it turns out, the auto-index does work. It do think it's counter-intuitive that it is not enumerated among other indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the automatic index feature? It's basically the use case you're looking for--unfortunately it needs to be enabled before you import the data. (Otherwise you have to remove/add the properties to reindex them.)

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/auto-indexing.html

Comment: I've been inching down that road, but not getting very far. I've updated the question to reflect my current lack of progress.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't done a lot of work with embedded, unfortunately. It's trivial with the REST service. I'll see if I can get someone to answer this.